# Throwing exception proactively vs Rethrowing vs Wrapping and Rethrowing

Tags: c#, exception

If I have a class doing something that can cause exceptions, is it best to throw an exception when I know that something is wrong, before the meat of the method executes, i.e.:

```
public class FileThingy
{
    public void Do(string filepath)
    {
        if(!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File not here!");
        }   

        // do file stuff
    }
}
```

Or wait until the exception I am expecting occurs re throw it:

```
public class FileThingy
{
    public void Do(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            // do file stuff stuff
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Or wait until the exception I am expecting occurs and wrap it in a new exception of a type that better describes it, and then throwing that:

```
public class FileThingy
{
    public void Do(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            // do file stuff
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File not here!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen all three of these being used in various places, and would like to know if any of these should be preferred, and if any of these are particularly harmful.

Comment: Your 1st example is pointless - if the file is not there, it'll throw anyway, checking doesn't buy you much. Your 2nd example is not wrapping anything, just re-throwing the same exception.

Comment: You left out the most common option: Do nothing. Let the caller catch any exceptions. Don't do more than that unless you have some concrete reason to do it. For example, if a parameter must not be null, don't just try to call a method on it and let `NullReferenceException` be thrown. Check for null and throw `ArgumentNullException` with the parameter name. That makes life easier for the caller. Mindlessly rethrowing is just useless typing practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fail fast is the best strategy, as long as you are not relying on implementation details that are supposed to be opaque to your code.

If your code accesses a specific file, and the file must exist, checking this prerequisite is essential. Reporting the problem as soon as you know it makes it easier to diagnose the issue to someone running your code.

Note that you need to trap the exception as well, because the file may get deleted between the moment that you checked for its existence and the moment that you actually need to read its content.

If opening the file is the first thing that your code does after checking for file's existence, then it is better to skip the check. On the other hand, if your code retrieves additional data before getting to the point where it actually opens the file, then checking proactively is a good idea.

If you are about to call some *other* method which you know is going to read a specific file, it is not a good idea to check for the existence of that file proactively. Newer method implementations may switch away from reading the file, e.g. to accessing a database, making your check invalid, and forcing you to change your code.

Comment: Just a small comment - I don't think checking the file's presence is of much value - if the check comes back true, opening the file may still fail with the same exception. Just opening it and dealing with the outcome is easier and better in my opinion.

Comment: @xxbbcc Thanks for the comment! I think it depends on what you do after checking for file's existence. If you proceed to opening it right away, then the check for existence of the file is redundant. If, on the other hand, you read lots of other stuff before opening the file, then it's better to check proactively. I made an edit to explain this.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation is clearer that way.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general rule is catch exceptions you can handle gracefully, allow exceptions you cannot handle to bubble up the stack and document any exceptions you throw including how to avoid them.